# github-api: Accessing/Downloading Files (without using `getArchive`)

Tags: amazon-s3, github-api

```
    var GitHubApi = require("github");

```
var github = new GitHubApi({
  debug: true
});

github.authenticate({
  type: "oauth",
  token: <token>
});

github.repos.getContent({
  user: "user-name",
  repo: "repo-with-build-dir",
  path: "./build",
  ref: "some-ref",
  }, function(err, res) {
    console.log(err, res.content);
});
```

```

the result I get back looks something like this: 

`[ 
  { name: '.htaccess', path: 'build/.htaccess', sha: 'someSha', size: 1787,
   url:'https://api.github.com/repos/sapo/fd1/contents/build/.htaccess?ref=refs/heads/development', 
 html_url:'https://github.com/sapo/fd1/blob/refs/heads/development/build/.htaccess',
  git_url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/sapo/fd1/git/blobs/someSha',
  download_url:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sameRepo/fd1/refs/heads/development/build/.htaccess?token=someToken',
  type: 'file' }
  ]`

## Problem/Issue

Whenever I attempt to access any the urls' directly in the browser - `html_url`, `git_url`, `download_url` - I get a `404 not found` error.

## What I am attempting to achieve:

I need to be able to pass a link to [S3.upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) method. So basically, copy these files to S3 bucket.

## Question

Can you please tell explain why I might be getting the 404 error? Also, any ideas on how I can use the urls' to download the contents of the file?  Appreciate any pointers I can get.

Thank you.

Comment: *"I need to be able to pass a link to S3.upload method"* I believe that once you solve your authentication issue, you'll find that you don't pass a "link" to `S3.upload`.  You pass a buffer, a blob, or a stream... so you'll need to download the files, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever I attempt to access any the urls' directly in the browser - html_url, git_url, download_url - I get a 404 not found error.

Since I cannot access https://github.com/sapo/fd1, I suppose it is a private repository.

See [Why am I getting a 404 error on a repository that exists?](https://developer.github.com/v3/troubleshooting/#why-am-i-getting-a-404-error-on-a-repository-that-exists)

> To troubleshoot, ensure you're [authenticating correctly](https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/), your [OAuth access token has the required scopes](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-scopes-for-oauth-apps/), and [third-party application restrictions are not blocking access](https://developer.github.com/changes/2015-01-19-an-integrators-guide-to-organization-application-policies/).